# What are the expected parameters when syncing PouchDB and Cloudant

Tags: pouchdb, cloudant

I am trying to setup replication between PouchDB and Cloudant using doc_ids array option

```
localpouchdb.sync(cloudantremoteDBURL, { doc_ids:['1450853987668'] })
```

Some error is thrown by cloudant

```
error: true
message: "Something wrong with the request"
name: "bad_request"
reason: "filter parameter must be of the form `designname/filtername`"
```

Anyone able to syn pouchDB with cloudant using doc_ids options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I raised a support ticket with IBM Cloudant, and confirmed that _doc_ids filter is not yet implemented in the cloudant. Following is the response from their support:

> Unfortunately, Cloudant doesn't currently implement the _doc_ids
>   filter on the _changes feed. We are planning a release early in the
>   new year which includes the latest CouchDB feature set, including the
>   _doc_ids filter.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs on `sync` http://pouchdb.com/api.html#sync you should be setting the source and target, then passing the `doc_ids` into the `options`

Something like

```
PouchDB.sync(localDB, cloudantremoteDBURL, { doc_ids:['1450853987668'] })
```

Comment: It is same as   localpouchDB.sync(cloudantremoteDBURL, { doc_ids:['1450853987668'] })